# DockLayoutPanel issues with text wrapping

Tags: gwt, layout, uibinder, docklayoutpanel

So I am using a dock layout panel. In the north I have a title and menubar and center has a table. My problem is when the title gets long and wraps the text, it pushed the menubar down and you can no longer see it. This is because you have to set fixed sizes for all panels except center.

I thought about moving it all to center panel but the problem is that when my table gets big and a scroll bar appears I want to always see the header and menubar even when scrolling on the table. So I cant just put everything in scroll panel.

How can I create a layout that fills these requirements:
1. Always see the title and menubar
2. Scrollable table
3. When the window is resized and text from title wraps it resizes the whole thing correctly.

here is Layout right now:

```
<g:DockLayoutPanel >
        <g:north size="80">
            <g:VerticalPanel width="100%">
                    <g:HorizontalPanel width="100%">
                        <g:HTML ui:field="title" styleName="{style.title}"></g:HTML>
                    </g:HorizontalPanel>
                    <g:HorizontalPanel styleName="{style.infoBar}" width="100%">
                        <g:MenuBar animationEnabled="true" styleName="{res.css.menuBar}" focusOnHoverEnabled="false" ui:field="menuBar"></g:MenuBar>
                    </g:HorizontalPanel>
                </g:VerticalPanel>
            </g:north>
            <g:center>
                <g:ScrollPanel>
                    <g:SimplePanel ui:field="content" styleName="{style.content}">Table or tree goes here
                    </g:SimplePanel>
                </g:ScrollPanel>
            </g:center>
            <g:south size="20">
                <g:VerticalPanel styleName="{style.footerPanel}">
                    <g:HTML ui:field="messageBar">Fotter text here</g:HTML>
                </g:VerticalPanel>
            </g:south>
        </g:DockLayoutPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use two DockLayoutPanel?

The first has the title in the center area and in the south another DockLayoutPanel with the menu in the north area and the table in the center?

Comment: I havn't tried this but unless I am mistaken since you have to have fixed size on the south panel, you couldn't put a docklayout panel inside it unless I set a fixed height for the table

Comment: You are right. I was thinking about the GXT BorderLayoutPanel. Have your tried to add two north areas to your DockPanel. One for the title and another for your menu.

Comment: This still does not solve the problem because you have to give the north panel a fixed size, however if the window gets too small and the text wraps, then it gets bigger than the set fixed size

Answer (score 0):

If title and menu may be shown underneath each other you can put title and menu in separate north-panels (that actually works).

With that you can at least ensure that the menu gets shown.

Comment: I mean yes it solves it so that the menu doesn't get hidden, but I was hoping for a complete solution.